# Why does it keep giving me te same errors?

Tags: sql, lua

So I wanted to put a sql file in a database `(es_extended.sql)` and it keeps giving me errors like: duplicate column name `name` etc. and

```
SQL error (1050): Table 'items' already exists
```

I have tried to change the names of columns and all but it keeps giving the same errors.

here is the code:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `users`

        ADD COLUMN  `money` VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    ADD COLUMN  `name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT '' AFTER `money`,
    ADD COLUMN  `skin` LONGTEXT NULL AFTER `name`,
    ADD COLUMN  `job` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT 'unemployed' AFTER `skin`,
    ADD COLUMN  `job_grade` INT NULL DEFAULT 0 AFTER `job`,
    ADD COLUMN  `loadout` LONGTEXT NULL AFTER `job_grade`,
    ADD COLUMN  `position` VARCHAR(36) NULL AFTER `loadout`
;

CREATE TABLE `items` (
    `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `label` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `limit` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
    `rare` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `can_remove` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',

    PRIMARY KEY (`name`)
);

CREATE TABLE `job_grades` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `job_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    `grade` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `label` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `salary` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `skin_male` longtext NOT NULL,
    `skin_female` longtext NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);


INSERT INTO `job_grades` VALUES (1,'unemployed',0,'unemployed','Unemployed',200,'{}','{}');

CREATE TABLE `jobs` (
    `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `label` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (`name`)
        
;

INSERT INTO `jobs` VALUES ('unemployed','Unemployed');

CREATE TABLE `user_accounts` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `identifier` varchar(22) NOT NULL,
    `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `money` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

);

CREATE TABLE `user_inventory` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `identifier` varchar(22) NOT NULL,
    `item` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `count` int(11) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sql databases are a way to implement the [persistence layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_(computer_science)#:%7E:text=complicated%20to%20debug.-,Persistence%20layers,an%20underlying%20database%20management%20system.): data that should be kept permanently or at least independently from sessions.

The error you're getting: `SQL error (1050): Table 'items' already exists` means that you've already created a table with the same name you're using to try and create a new table.

You do not need to recreate the table each time you try to add data to it. The table is persistent as long as you do not `DROP` (delete) it or the database it belongs to.

If you want to recreate the table (either because you need to change its schema or because you want to start over), you can run the command `DROP TABLE items` which will delete the table and all data in the table.

After dropping, you can run the `CREATE TABLE items...` command again.

If you don't want to delete the table, you can just run the `INSERT INTO items...` command to add data to the existing table.

The `SQL Error (xxxx): duplicate column name 'name'` error means you are trying to add a column that already exists in the table. If the `users` table already has a column called `name`, then you cannot run the command `ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN 'name'...` without an error.

If the column doesn't meet your needs anymore, you can use `ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN 'name'...` to change the schema for the column.

Comment: Thanks! but what about the error: SQL Error (1060): Duplicate column name 'skin'
I have tried to change the names of the columns but it didnt work

Comment: I edited my answer to include the other error. Basically, it looks like you are trying to add a column that already exists. You either need to remove the column and add it again  (which will delete data in the column) or you will need to modify the column (which may delete data depending on how you modify it).